# Sharepoint web part menu does not display

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, web-parts

I'm trying to make some simple changes on a website that was built with SharePoint, specifically I'd like to edit a search widget, which is a "web part." (I'm not at all familiar with SharePoint!!!)

When I navigate to the web page >> Site Actions >> Edit Page, an arrow for a dropdown is available, but when I click on it i receive multiple javascript errors and the dropdown is not displayed.

These are the javascript errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: OpenWebPartMenuFromLink is not defined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: OpenWebPartMenu is not defined`

It appears that the page is missing a javascript library. My best guess is that it should be included in default.master but I'm not sure it that's true and I dont know what javascript library should be included. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Currently I see these references to javascript in my default.master header

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" defer="true" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have messed up the new master page. Best thing to do is take a copy of V4.master & work on it

Answer (score 0):

try to find in your master page this code before ribbon div (`<div id="ms-designer-ribbon">`)

```
<!--MS:<IS:SuppressScipts runat="server"/>-->
```

or something like this
and delete it

I have the same problem and it helped me